# How to deploy a vue3 application in a apache2 server?

Tags: javascript, apache2, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to make a vue3 app run in a apache2 server, I did apache configuration of the site in sites-available and also did the symlink to sites-enabled. I don't have the ServerName ready bc I wanted to test it using the direct path from /var and when it's ready use the DNS. Here is the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        # ServerName xyz.example.com.br
        # ServerAlias xyz.example.com.br

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/agenda/dist

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and my app is at var/www/html with the dist folder generated from *yarn run build*, as it is referenced in the file above. Here is the index.html from the dist folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/hrg.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Agenda Eletrônica</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index.02c23677.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/index.db6e77a5.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I added the dot before the href links because otherwise it interprets as the files are located at the /, not /dist (at least it was happening with the js file).

Anyways it just does not work. When I access the IP of the server followed by /agenda/dist it does not show anything, only favicon is loaded. It also doesn't bring any errors on browser console.

I would try to use nginx, but we do not use it here so I would like to keep it that way and only use it if necessary (maybe that's the case).

P.S: I'm using vite

Comment: Since this is not a question about programming, it will possibly be downvoted or closed. There is the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) site for questions about server administration and  configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I will leave it here if more people get stuck on it.

I am using Vue Router and in the index there are only two routes

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home },
  { path: "/unidade/:id", name: "Andares", component: UnityHome },
];
```

As I didn't have the DNS ready and was trying to access it direct from /var path, as it is not a valid route in this file it does not show anything. Now with the DNS it works, because it is the correct path.

So just use a DNS already or change the route file to, in my case, /agenda/dist

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/agenda/dist", name: "Home", component: Home },
  { path: "/unidade/:id", name: "Andares", component: UnityHome },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you problem has nothing to do with Vue3 and is based on the improper apache2 configuration.

I am not sure, since I have configured apache2 for 10 years at least, but if your app is in `/var/www/html` then why your `DocumentRoot` points to `/var/www/html/agenda/dist` ?

Shouldn't it then point to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/` ?

Comment: agenda is the folder of my application. Inside agenda there is the dist folder, a bundle served for static hosting service. I have to use the index.html that there is in the dist (so I just point to it), otherwise it will try to read typescript file because it will read the index.html in my DocumentRoot, not the one inside the dist folder which references the compiled typescript (index.02c23677.js)
here is the link to a better explaining of [dist folder](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html)

Comment: Ok. Then try to analyze the loading of resources using the Network  in Browser Dev Tools and apache2 access log.

Comment: In network it gets the files just fine, status 200 for all. In the apache2 log it also shows a 200 response.

Comment: Then check the javascript console for the errors.

Comment: I found the solution, I'll write the response